# Boolean Algebra-Simplification Assistance Needed

Tags: logic, computer-science, boolean-logic, boolean-expression, simplify

I have to show that (!P.!Q+R)(!Q+P.!R) => !Q by simplifying it using De Morgan's Laws.
Here is what I did but I'm not sure it's right.

**(!P.!Q + R)(!Q + P.!R) => !Q**

**(!P + !Q + R)(!Q + P.!R)**

**!P.!Q + !P.P.!R + !Q.!Q + !Q.P.!R + R.!Q + R.P.!R**

**!P.!Q + 0 + !Q + !Q.P.!Q + R.!Q + 0**

**!P.!Q + !Q + !Q(1 + P.!R + R)**

**!P.!Q + !Q + !Q**

**!Q + !P.!Q**

**!Q(1 + !P)**

**!Q**

Hope that's clear enough.

Comment: How did you go from `!P!Q` on the first line to `!P + !Q` on the second?

Comment: De Morgan's Laws !(P.Q) = !P + !Q, did I do it wrong?

Comment: `!(!P.!Q) = P + Q` or `!(P.Q) = !P + !Q`, not `!P!Q = !P + !Q`. Consider when `P = 1`, `Q = 0` - `!P!Q = 0`, but `!P + !Q = 1`.

Comment: Ok I thanks, I'll do it again. Just for future reference how is !(P.Q) different from P.Q NOT as in P.Q with the line above it, I'm not sure how to type it out.

Comment: Um I'm not sure how to type it out but in the first line it's !(P.Q) instead of !P.!Q I think, it's P.Q Negated, as in with the line above it, so wouldn't my next line be correct?

Comment: Yes, if it's `!(P.Q)`, then your next line is correct.